# ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host, unable to connect to heroku app

Tags: git, heroku

I am trying to push into heroku under college proxy:

Output of ssh -vvv git@heroku.com

```
OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-3ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/vineel/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for heroku.com
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 25: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec corkscrew 10.3.100.211 8080 ssh.heroku.com 443
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 1000
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/vineel/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/vineel/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/vineel/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vineel/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vineel/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vineel/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vineel/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I added this to my /etc/ssh_config file:

```
Host heroku.com
    Hostname ssh.heroku.com
    User git
    ProxyCommand corkscrew 10.3.100.211 8080 %h %p
    Port 443
    Hostname ssh.heroku.com
```

my hosts.allow file:

```
# /etc/hosts.allow: list of hosts that are allowed to access the system.
#                   See the manual pages hosts_access(5) and hosts_options(5).
#
# Example:    ALL: LOCAL @some_netgroup
#             ALL: .foobar.edu EXCEPT terminalserver.foobar.edu
#
# If you're going to protect the portmapper use the name "portmap" for the
# daemon name. Remember that you can only use the keyword "ALL" and IP
# addresses (NOT host or domain names) for the portmapper, as well as for
# rpc.mountd (the NFS mount daemon). See portmap(8) and rpc.mountd(8)
# for further information.
#
SSHD: ALL
```